# Как java управляет объектами и памятью в данном примере?

Tags: java

Нормально ли переиспользовать переменные вот так после добавления в лист?

```java
List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
Person huego = new Person("Huego");
personList.add(huego);
huego = new Person("Michael");
personList.add(huego); // [Person{name='Huego'}, Person{name='Michael'}]
System.out.println(personList);
```

Мы видим, что когда я изменил ссылку `huego` на новый объект `Michael`, - ничего не изменилось со старым `huego` в арейлисте. Почему так?

`huego` теперь показывается, как `Michael`, и если я изменю значение переменной для него, то поменяется только для `Michael`.
Почему `Huego` продолжает жить как объект, если я изменил ссылку со стэка на `Michael` и на `huego` ничего не должно ссылаться.

Вопросы глупые, но что поделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что вы используете оператор new. Вы создаёте новый объект, а не переназначаете ссылку на него отовсюду. Объект внутри List ничего не знает об этом. Он по прежнему хранит первую ссылку, крепко вцепившись в неё руками. Попробуйте посмотреть следующую конструкцию.

```
    public class Person {
    private String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

=======

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
    Person huego = new Person("Huego");
    personList.add(huego);
    huego.setName("huego 2");
    personList.add(huego);
    // [Person{name='huego 2'}, Person{name='huego 2'}]
    System.out.println(personList.toString());


    // чтобы реально изменить ссылку
    huego = new Person("Michael");
    personList.set(0, huego);
    System.out.println(personList.toString());

    // [Person{name='Michael'}, Person{name='huego 2'}]

    huego = null;
    // ничего не сломается

    System.out.println(personList.toString());

}
```